Converting functions to methods in Python 3.12
I have a Python program that has 1,000s of functions (def), and none of them are using classes.
Is there an automated way to convert these functions into class methods? I would group related functions together as needed.
I tried snippets (Python 3.x), and python code, but nothing worked as expected.

How about grouping them in modules instead?

Give an example please

You don't put functions in classes just for organization purposes. Classes serve a specific function in OOP.

Why do you want to do that?
